# Malicious script injecting adware in my Wordpress instance

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

Some malware is injecting this script somewhere in my wordpress main page. I already went through all files in Editor but I find nothing about this. Any idea where can I find it? Its driving me crazy.

This script is injecting adware popups in my wordpress website.

[image]

Comment: It could be one of your templates or widgets. This link *may* help: https://wordpress.org/support/topic/how-to-add-javascript-code-for-ads-to-my-blog

Comment: if you have still access to the backend you can try an audit with Wordfence, and grep all files (and I really mean all files) for suspicious strings like eval(, base64_decode( and so on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try downloading the whole theme folder and plugins folder (with all plugins). Then you would need to run search across all those files. Usually malware code is using eval functions so you should search for eval across all those files. Searching one by one would take forever so use grep tool.

For windows I would recommend windows grep 
http://www.wingrep.com/

For Mac I would recommend visualGrep app which is paid app and costs around 2 bucks but totally worth it.

If you have linux then you would need to find the software yourself or you can run such a search from the command line. (Actually you can use CLI on any system but I just prefer having app with GUI fur such task)

in 99% of cases (from my experience) you will find something like:

eval(base64_decode('dsalkndsalndsnldakslasdkn'));

That will be the malware code and you should take care of it (remove). If the code is in the plugin, then you should get rid of such a plugin probably.

Hope this helps.

Comment: better fix the changed files and remove added files and put up some protection, many plugins have vulnerabilities, see https://wpvulndb.com

Comment: better also check the database